# Is there any way to mass-change winform label names at one time?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a form with about ~400 Labels with random names such as '1', '00a', '241c' '1251', etc. I want to give them new names that increment, such as 'lbl001', 'lbl002', 'lbl003'...

Changing them manually takes several seconds for each one. Is there a way to speed this up or handle all of them at once?

Comment: What UI framework are you using, Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: @YayCplusplus there is no way yo can change it..only the other properties can be change if all labelshas been selected and the name can't because it is must be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a script to iterate over all declarations of Labels in the Form.Designer.cs and replace each name it finds with a the value of the loop's counter + a prefix.

You can find Label declarations using Regular Expressions, and then iterate through the list of matches.